# diffrence between ANOSIM and Deseq2

Tags: statistics, taxonomy, multivariate-testing

What is the difference between ANOSIM test and differential expression analysis like Deseq2? And what are the limitations of using ANOSIM over Deseq2 when comes to differential analysis between various sample groups ?

Thank you